# probability of getting 50 heads from tossing a coin 100 times

Tags: probability

folks,

i am new to this forum and not a math expert. so please bear with me if am asking silly questions.

The question is "probability of getting 50 heads from tossing a coin 100 times".

So the answer for this is, I guess, ${100 \choose 50} (2 ^{-100})$.

So all am trying to get is easier way to calculate ${100 \choose 50}$, or another approach to the parent problem only.

Thanks all, appreciate that.

raj

Comment: I guess you mean 2^{-100}, but you are correct.  To estimate this number you can use Stirling's formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

Comment: oh yes.. thanks for poiting out the typo...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coefficient ${2n \choose n}$ for $n$ large can be approximated well (using Stirling's formula) by ${2n \choose n} \approx 4^n / \sqrt{n \pi} $. In particular, letting $n=50$ gives ${100 \choose 50} \approx 4^{50}/ \sqrt {50 \pi}$.

Comment: Another approach is approximating the binomial with a normal distribution, i.e. N(np,np(1-p))=N(50,25) and interpolating the desired value from a standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 4):

See [How to calculate binomial probabilities](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/04/24/how-to-calculate-binomial-probabilities/) for how to calculate these probabilities while avoiding numerical overflow or underflow.

Also, I believe you meant to type 2^-100 instead of 2^-10 in your question.

Comment: yes John, thanks for pointing out the typo...

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in question here, of course, can be computed exactly.  For example, using [bignum](http://gmplib.org/) or [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) (or even [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) -- the exactly link won't work on here, but I'm sure you can type in "(100 choose 50)*2^(-100)" yourself).

On my home computer, in GAP, it took less than a millisecond.  To make it more interesting, I also computed ${100000 \choose 50000} \cdot 2^{-100000}$, which took a bit more than 17 seconds.

```
gap> Binomial(100,50)/2^100;
12611418068195524166851562157/158456325028528675187087900672
gap> time;
0
gap> Binomial(100000,50000)/2^100000;
<<an integer too large to be printed>>/<<an integer too large to be printed>>
gap> time;
17266
```

In fact, provided the coin has probability 1/2, the probability will always have a terminating decimal expansion (since binomial coefficients are integers, and 2 divides 10).  Here it is in this case:

```
0.0795892373871787614981270502421704614029315404247333213573478705171737601631321012973785400390625
```